# How can I implement server notifications in JavaScript and what are the pros/cons of each method?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I would like to implement push notifications to a JavaScript client-side application. I have read many articles on the web that show different possibilities (WebSockeds, AJAX poll/long poll, server-Sent events...) and now I'm really unsure on how I should implement them. From the experience of a JavaScript front-end developer, what are the possible ways (currently available) to implement this, and what are the pros/cons of using each possibility?

(I could try each one of them, but as I don't have much experience in the field, I don't have the experience to know what problems could arise in each implementation, i.e. # of open connections, latency, etc.)

Comment: WebSockets are state of the art. SSE will do if you don't need bidirectional communication. Ajax (long) polling is only a fallback.